# Как перехватить экспортируемое значение из vue-массива для вставки в js-код

Tags: vue.js, vuetify

Подскажите пожалуйста как "вытащить" значение из массива vue и вставить в js-код, в нужное (отметил) место? В html всё получается, а вот в js выводит ошибку. Перерыл инет, но подобного не нашёл.

```
<template>
  <v-app>
.
.
.
          <v-list>
            <v-list-tile
              v-for="(item, index) in menuItems"
              :key="index"
              :href="'/'+item.locale"   <!-- тут экспортируемое значение item.locale нормально работает -->
              @click="buttonClick"
            >
              <v-list-tile-title>{{ item.title }}</v-list-tile-title>
            </v-list-tile>
          </v-list>
.
.
.
  </v-app>
</template>


<script>
  // импортируем библиотеку tiny-cookie
  import { getCookie, setCookie } from 'tiny-cookie'

  export default {
    data: () => ({
      dialog: false,
      drawer: null,
      menuItems: [
        { locale: 'ru', title: 'Русский' },
        { locale: 'en', title: 'English' },
        { locale: 'ko', title: '한국어' }
      ],
    }),
    methods:{
      buttonClick: function() {

        // пишем локаль в кукисы
        const flag = true
        setCookie('flag', flag)
        setCookie('language', item.locale ) // сюда нужно вставить, но item.locale выдает ошибку
      }
    },
    props: {
      source: String
    }
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Решение подсказали: Андрей @muzikant777 и Alex @potapchino

```js
methods: {
  buttonClick(item) {
    ...
    setCookie('language', item.locale)
  }
}
```

```html
<v-list-tile
  ...
  @click="buttonClick(item)">
```